# Is it allowed to stay at night in Old Town San Diego State Historic Park?

Tags: nightlife, san-diego, parks-and-gardens

[image: San Diego State Historic Park]

Is it allowed to stay at night in [Old Town San Diego State Historic Park](https://mwtgo.com/old-town-san-diego-state-historic-park/)?

Comment: Have you been there?  It's an urban historic park, not conducive to camping (if that's what you're referring to by "stay the night")

Comment: @Midavalo Yes, actually I have.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica my comment was intended for the OP 

Comment: @Midavalo Sorry for misunderstanding, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The California State Parks webpage](http://parks.ca.gov/?page_id=663) of the Old Town San Diego State Historic Park (SHP) says:

> **Park Hours**
>
> Visitor Center & Museums 10:00 AM - 5:00 PM
>
> Park Restrooms Open 10am-Dusk; Concession Restrooms may be open longer.
>
> Museums are closed Thanksgiving, Christmas, and New Years Day.

Thus, the governmental part (visitor center, museums) of the SHP closes at 5:00 p.m.

The SHP, however, is a built-up area of historic buildings and streets. [This non-governmental page](https://www.oldtownsandiego.org/state-historic-park/) contains this illustration:

[image]

The illustration doesn't show pedestrian or vehicle barriers.

The earlier-cited SHP page says concession restrooms may stay open later. Restaurants and specialty shops and hotels are located within the SHP, and listed on [this non-governmental page](https://www.oldtownsandiego.org/dining/). I looked at a few restaurant listings, which show closing times of 8:00 and 9:00 p.m. The Cosmopolitan Hotel is shown as "open," while the Cosmopolitan Hotel Restaurant is "closed."

Looks like the Cosmopolitan Hotel is at this moment the only option for staying overnight within the SHP.

Comment: The park is not fenced/gated, pedestrians can access from almost any side at any time

Comment: I agree. We don't know what the OP means by "stay at night." If they mean "walk around or stand on a street corner," then probably yes. If "in a restaurant," then yes again while the restaurant is open. If they mean "in a lodging or camping," then only at the Cosmopolitan Hotel. I cannot imagine that pitching a tent or unrolling a sleeping bag would be tolerated.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica *pitching a tent or unrolling a sleeping bag would be tolerated* => given that this is in California you’d be surprised :-)

Comment: @JonathanReez I live in California, and am quite familiar with street life and homelessness. There are several state parks (and a state historic park) in my town, and the unhoused do _not_ set up in those locations. I suspect the same would be true in San Diego.